# Notice: Only variables should be passed by reference in C:\xampp\htdocs\auth\register.php on line 12 Success

Tags: php

```
<?php 

require 'database.php';


if (isset($_POST['email']) && isset($_POST['password'])):



    // Enter the new user in the database

    $sql = "INSERT INTO users (email, password) VALUES (:email, :password)"; 

    $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);



    $stmt->bindParam(':email', $_POST['email']);

    $stmt->bindParam(':password', password_hash($_POST['password'], PASSWORD_BCRYPT));

    if( $stmt->execute() ):

        die('Success');

    else:

        die('Fail');

    endif;


endif;


 ?>
```

It successfully add the user and password in the database but it gives the error below

> Only variables should be passed by reference in C:\xampp\htdocs\auth\register.php on line 12

Comment: Where's the error?

Comment: Only variables should be passed by reference in C:\xampp\htdocs\auth\register.php on line 12

Comment: What's "line 12"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The format for bindParam is as follows:

```
public bool PDOStatement::bindParam ( mixed $parameter , mixed &$variable [, int $data_type = PDO::PARAM_STR [, int $length [, mixed $driver_options ]]] )
```

Notice this part `mixed &$variable` is passed by reference.
To fix this, just change:

```
$stmt->bindParam(':password', password_hash($_POST['password'], PASSWORD_BCRYPT));
```

To:

```
$password = password_hash($_POST['password'], PASSWORD_BCRYPT);
$stmt->bindParam(':password', $password);
```

Since you are then passing a variable itself by reference, not just the string returned by `password_hash()`.

Comment: oh i see now... thank you :)